# Visualizing TurtleBot kinect Data error

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I recently start to play with Turtlebot, when I try the tutorial of Visulizing TurtleBot Kinect Data, after I type:

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch

there are some errors like this:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [7720]
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [7721]
process[openni_camera-3]: started with pid [7722]
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [7723]
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [7724]
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [7731]
[ERROR] [1340413781.772649065]: Failed to load nodelet [/pointcloud_throttle] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/lib/libcloud_to_scan.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1340413781.791983076]: Service call failed!
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 7723, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/471a8646-bccd-11e1-883b-485d6075585d/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [7858]
[ERROR] [1340413782.519281033]: Failed to load nodelet [/kinect_laser] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/lib/libcloud_to_scan.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1340413782.536469410]: Service call failed!
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 7724, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/471a8646-bccd-11e1-883b-485d6075585d/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [7881]
[ERROR] [1340413783.260549262]: Failed to load nodelet [/kinect_laser_narrow] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/lib/libcloud_to_scan.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1340413783.278743552]: Service call failed!
[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/471a8646-bccd-11e1-883b-485d6075585d/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 7731, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/471a8646-bccd-11e1-883b-485d6075585d/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [7906]
[ERROR] [1340413784.086976933]: Failed to load nodelet [/openni_camera] of type [openni_camera/OpenNINodelet]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1340413784.106074772]: Service call failed!
[openni_camera-3] process has died [pid 7722, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/471a8646-bccd-11e1-883b-485d6075585d/openni_camera-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_camera-3] restarting process
.....
```

then I thought it might be because I recharging my iRobot and I need to restart the
openni_camera nodelet. So I type:

```
roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

but unfortunately get another error like this:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[openni_node1-1]: started with pid [6535]
process[kinect_base_link-2]: started with pid [6536]
process[kinect_base_link1-3]: started with pid [6537]
process[kinect_base_link2-4]: started with pid [6538]
process[kinect_base_link3-5]: started with pid [6544]
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/bin/openni_node: relocation error: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[openni_node1-1] process has died [pid 6535, exit code 127].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/471a8646-bccd-11e1-883b-485d6075585d/openni_node1-1*.log
```

Anyone has some suggestions to resolve this problem? Thanks.
PS: all the previous turtorials are running ok for my turtlebot and workstation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37114/visualizing-turtlebot-kinect-data-error/) by [jokyzhuang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2674/jokyzhuang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Just resolved the problem. It seems the libmysqlclient was missing.
Tried: sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient16 and everything is OK now.

---

Originally posted by [jokyzhuang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2674/jokyzhuang/) with karma: 46 on 2012-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2